# Photoshop shows only "Helvetica Neue Regular", whereas everything else in the system does not

Tags: windows-8.1, fonts, adobe-photoshop

I am having a devil of a time with a font that only Photoshop sees, and only Photoshop works with.

I need the entire Helvetica Neue font range installed into my system for Photoshop to use, but it can only see Helvetica Neue Regular, which is what came with the system. I have already uninstalled all Helvetica fonts on the system, but for some reason Photoshop still sees and uses that Neue Regular font.

I need a way to excise Helvetica Neue Regular completely (it has no subtypes under Photoshop), and install the regular Helvetica Neue range (which does not show up under Photoshop at all, even though it is available to the rest of the system).

To be absolutely clear: when I uninstall all Helvetica fonts, only Photoshop still shows and is able to use a Helvetica font: the Helvetica Neue Regular, which is NOT A PART OF the Helvetica Neue line I am trying to install. When I go to install any other Helvetica Neue (not Regular) font, any other program on the system can see and use that new font, but Photoshop still shows Regular and does not show that new font.

I have already cleared out the Fonts app under the Control panel, and have confirmed under C:\Windows\Fonts that no Helvetica fonts remain on the system.

I have also confirmed that

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\Fonts

Is empty.

Suggestions?

---

**Edit:**

I have also found [this document](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/troubleshoot-fonts-photoshop.html) and have employed steps 1-3, 6-8. That damned Helvetica Neue Regular font still “appears” in Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue too. Use Font editors like font forge to edit the name of the new font you wish to install before installing it, if there is no easy way to remove the existing ones.

Comment: The problem isn’t removing existing ones -- that is easy. The problem is that even after ALL HELVETICA FONTS have been REMOVED, Photoshop CAN STILL SEE AND USE THEM. I mean, WTF Photoshop??